# mysql utf8mb4 turkish character confusion

Tags: mysql, turkish

I am inserting some datas including turkish characters into a table and when I insert a data appearance of turkish characters confused me. For example for the character 'ğ', appearance on database is 'ð'. But when I get data and print it on the browser for testing this character shows up to be correct 'ğ' character. Do I have to worry about the situation ? (Btw I am using utf8mb4 as described in title)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using phpmyadmin to see database entries, it is a common misconception.

You shouldn't worry and you can configure it from php.ini and phpmyadmin's settings. But as you said it is not much of a problem. I reccomend you to use toad or navicat for mysql for better results.